# javascript Date.parse 0000-00-00 00:00 AM format results in NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, timestamp

I am trying to parse a date string to javascript timestamp, the format of the string is `2013-01-01 12:00 AM` but when I attempt to alert the output all I can get is `NaN` My attempt is:

```
var ts_begin = Date.parse($('#fromdate').val()+' '+$('#fromtime').val());
alert(ts_begin);
```

Comment: Can you put alert($('#fromdate').val());  alert($('#fromtime').val());
before alert(ts_begin) and tell us what you are getting?

Comment: quoting from the post `2013-01-01 12:00 AM` is the string currently

Answer (score 2):

The [`parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method is very picky on what date formats it accepts. You may want to look at another JavaScript library called [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to parse your dates (it can also do a lot more with date/time values).

Answer (score 1):

`Date.parse` can only use specific formats.  It's not a fan of the lack of space before AM/PM.  Try:

```
Date.parse($("#fromdate").val() + ' ' + $("#fromtime").val()
   .replace(/[AP]M/, ' $&'));
```

Comment: I see a space in OP's `2013-01-01 12:00 AM`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté you're right; I tried and it works in my browser with the space but not without so it might be browser dependent.  It's also easy to just replace the ` [AP]M` with `:00`, but that does require increasing the time value.

Comment: Can be done using a function as the second parameter of the replace with a slightly more complicated regex. `=]` I usually don't rely on `Date.parse` and prefer building up a new Date object from splitting/regexing the string but yeah, shorter code that works is always nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
var utc_timestamp = Date.UTC(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 
    now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds(), now.getMilliseconds());
alert(utc_timestamp);
```

Comment: I guess OP is looking to transform a given string into a timestamp and not simply getting the current timestamp.

Comment: ya true what u said.. am sorry about the post then.. i can never reach 10.6k without giving a few good answers at least i suppose. dying to make a start somehow..